# Подскажите, пожалуйста, раздел языкознания

Tags: языкознание

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой раздел языкознания занимается крылатыми, но не выражениями, я словами? Ну, например, плохого врача называют "коновал". Фразеология, по идее, занимается фразами, а этимология - просто происхождением слов. А тут нужно узнать, почему называют именно так, а не иначе. Извините, если путано объясняю.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен с   bernard, вряд ли существует специальный раздел языкознания, изучающий такие слова. Скорее всего такими словами занимается или лексикология, ну, или, неспециальная литиратура по русскому, предназначенная для массового читателя. Ну,  например " Я познаю мир. Русский язык". "В глубь поговорки".Автор: В.М. Мокиенко ( в  последней как раз рассказывается не только о поговорках, но и таких интересных слов).Есть еще одна книга: "Лингвистические парадоксы".Автор: В.В. Одинцов.

Comment: Если,  знать  исходное  значение  слова  "коновал",  то  его  современное  значение  не  вызывает  никаких  особенных  вопросов.  К  разряду  крылатых  оно  не  относится.  Исходное  значение  изменилось,  но  современное - плохой  врач - практически  одно.

Answer (score 2):

Коновал
Материал из Википедии — свободной энциклопедии

Коновал — лекарь, традиционно занимавшийся лечением домашней скотины в русских деревнях.

Ныне его обязанности выполняет ветеринарный врач, однако существенным отличием коновалов являлось то, что они были самоучками, то есть не получали соответствующего систематического образования. Чаще всего искусство лечения домашних животных традиционно передавалось из поколения в поколение или же согласно традициям ученичества от коновала его помощникам.

Одной из основных обязанностей коновала было охолащивание (кастрация) самцов (быков, баранов, поросят и жеребцов). Основной причиной для выполнения такой операции было то, что охолощенные самцы были более спокойны, а также лучше набирали вес. С этой обязанностью связано и происхождение названия коновал: для осуществления кастрации животных (в частности, коня) их было необходимо уложить (повалить) на землю.

Как правило, коновалы ходили по деревням в окрестностях собственного места жительства, предлагая свои услуги. Из-за специфики ремесла, связанного с противостоянием воспроизводству жизни, работа коновалов обрастала мифами и небылицами мистического свойства.

Ремесло коновала упоминается в рассказе Михаила Шолохова «Батраки» и в повести Анатолия Иванова «Повитель».

В современном языке и в литературе слово «коновал» может употребляться в качестве оскорбительного по отношению к врачу или ветеринару, при этом подразумевается, что он не обладает должной квалификацией, и плохо справляется со своими обязанностями.

Comment: Скорее  всего  никакого  особого  раздела  языкознания  для  изучения  таких  слов  нет.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос? Тут же человек просит не разъяснить слово "коновал", которое, думаю, понятно и первокласснику, с подсказать, какой раздел языкознания изучает это слово.

Comment: Почему  не  понял. Тут  два  вопроса.  1) Исходное  значение  слова, из  которого  вытекает  современное  значение - ответил;  2) раздел  языкознания - тоже  ответил, в  комментарии.  Думаю,  что  слово  коновал  всё  же  не  понятно  первокласснику.  Даже  в  современном  значении.